# Cannot reach some websites within AWS-lambda function

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jsoup

I am creating an AWS lambda function to do some basic web scraping using JSoup. I've setup the necessary VPC and corresponding requirements (I think).

When I execute the lambda function through the AWS testing interface I can successfully connect to basic websites such as google/cnn/etc  (https://www.google.com/) and (https://www.cnn.com/).

However, when I try to **scrape** the website I am interested in

https://www.wordplays.com/crossword-solver/egyptian-snake/

I get an IO exception:

org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403.

However, when I run the same code locally (on my computer) with that URL it is able to connect and read the website completely fine. This makes me think that my VPC is setup incorrectly but I don't know why I would be able to reach [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and not [www.wordplays.com](http://www.wordplays.com).

This is how I am invoking jsoup:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(html)
     .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36")
     .get();
```

I am not sure how to move forward since I cannot figure out why I can successfully connect to some websites but not others.

Comment: Does the same code work from your computer (outside of Lambda)? PS the term is scraping, not scrapping.

Comment: yes it does work outside the lambda, and thanks I will update

Comment: If your client's GET request is identical inside of Lambda (including user agent and other headers) then I would guess that the web server is rejecting your request. 403 means forbidden. It might be blocking AWS IP ranges, for example, because of prior misconduct on the part of other people, perhaps trying to DDoS the site or aggressively scraping it.

Comment: @jarmod that is an interesting idea, do you know of any way I could test this in order to know for certain?

Comment: Make an HTTP request that's identical with the exception of the source IP. Assuming that web scraping of that site is within their terms of use, you could also reach out to their tech support to investigate further.

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ not scrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the website blocks you. Many websites block Amazon AWS IP address range to protect their data from web crawlers. In fact, the AWS range is likely the most blocked range out there. Behavior depends on the implementation but quite often the website returns `4xx` error or lets request time-out.

You can try to use a proxy server that is out of the AWS range.

In the case of a larger website, the overcoming of protection might be more complicated and you may need a full browser to do so. My colleague wrote an article on this topic - https://help.apify.com/en/articles/1961361-several-tips-how-to-bypass-website-anti-scraping-protections . But in 99% cases, a proxy server will solve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

A Lambda function in a VPC needs subnetting as it does not have a public IP address.

If you want your Lambda function to access the internet it needs to do so using a NAT Gateway*. If the subset only has internet access though an IGW the Lambda function will not be able to communicate with the internet as it does not have, and can not receive, a public IP address.

*Charges Apply

Comment: While this is true, it would not result in a `403 Forbidden` error, which indicates that the far-end system is being successfully contacted but refuses to service the request.

Comment: yea the VPC/subnets/NAT gateway are setup fine the lambda can reach most sites fine just not the one mentioned above. Thank you though