# python bypass 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url on AWS server (works locally)

Tags: python, aws-lambda, python-requests, http-status-code-403

**[ISSUE]**
I am trying to python request a link that has no issues from my PC, but fails when it's running on AWS. Any chance to bypass that ? I guess it is due to some kind of blacklist ? I checked the site's robot.txt and it is indeed Disallowed, but since it's working fine from my PC I was wondering if there is some way to have it work on AWS as well with some kind of spoofing ? This is definetly not my speciality so any advice would be most welcome.

an example of what works locally and not on AWS:

```py
import requests
URL = "https://www.doctolib.fr/availabilities.json?start_date=2000-01-01&visit_motive_ids=2436062&agenda_ids=146770&practice_ids=56887&limit=2"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3"
}
response = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
response.raise_for_status()  # Check for any request errors
```

AWS logs will give this : `Error: Unable to fetch JSON data from the URL: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://www.doctolib.fr/availabilities.json?start_date=2000-01-01&visit_motive_ids=2436062&agenda_ids=146770&practice_ids=56887&limit=2&availabilities=1`

**[CONTEXT]**
I am trying to create a program that parses the main french medical appointment site (https://doctolib.fr) and sends you an email whenever a slot opens up within a certain timeframe. I kind of hate making appointments 6 months in advance, and I rather have some code telling me whenever someone cancelled. Of course, they did not provide an API, or else it's be too easy : [My code is here](https://github.com/smtgpm/doctolib-availability-reminder/tree/master), it's my first repo ever and definetly still in early stages, and as you can see parsing is not my speciality. But I'm still having a lot of fun creating this!

Comment: You can check this one
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59568584/cannot-reach-some-websites-within-aws-lambda-function

Comment: Ah indeed I thought I had looked on other topics, I guess not well enough. Thanks I'll look into it tomorrow